# Android: Signed Apk file does not include external library and throws "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, apk

I recently signed an apk file for release on Google Play and when I downloaded the application on Google Play and installed it, it would throw java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError.

My co-worker and I are suspecting that the library was not being added to our signed apk file.

We added our additional library to our project by adding it to our build path for the project.

Also, the library we are trying to add to our project is ActionBarSherlock.

Is there a reason why our library is not being included in our signed apk file, because we notice the file size for our signed apk is alot smaller than our unsigned version?

Can anyone point us in the right direction in signing our apk file correctly so that it includes the library we added into our build path?

Comment: Can you check if the sherlock library added as android dependency or it is in the lib folder of your project structure?

Comment: ActionBatSherlock is a separate project included in the build path. I just checked and we have it as an android dependency.

Comment: May be, you may like to have that jar which is generated and added in android dependency copied over to lib directory and then add that jar in the build path. Can you try that?

Comment: The reason I am asking you to do this is, if you have that jar in android dependency that means the application will expect it to have it in android's system library folder for framework but this is external lib and you should have it in lib folder so that it will get included with your apk.

Comment: Well just to let you know, I do have sherlock  added to my project and I just exported signed apk and there is absolutely no issue in running that. I do have that added as per the sherlock video which is exactly the case you have. I think your problem is something else. Do you use any native library in your application?

Comment: We tried adding the jars into a lib folder and putting it in the build path, but it broke the program. We are unsure why our release version is different then the one we build in eclipse because it works fine when we run it on the emulator/or phone. Thanks for helping us on Vendetta

Comment: Btw which version of android you are testing with currently.

Comment: We are testing with various android version from 2.3-4.1. I believe we got it working now after some hacking around. We did a build in eclipse. Got rid of the meta folder and resigned it. For now its a quick/dirty solution until we can properly fix it. Thank you for your help again Vendetta

Comment: You are welcome. I think you can put your temp fix as answer. As it may help someone else facing same issue. Also, if you have rights you can mark it correct.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same error missing **android.support.v4** jar file. deeJ is right if you look at ActionBarSherlock website it tells you to add the following in your proguard file:

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the problem was Proguard not playing well with ActionBarSherlock. Try using tips given here:

http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on your exact build process, my suggestion would be to use Maven for your builds. It might be that your dependancies are only used on your debug build rather than your release build. Another thing I would suggest, before putting something on the app store use the Android Debug Bridge (adb) to manually install it on a device and check for these kinds of errors.